# Custom user profile property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search-results, people-search

I have enabled search and in People search when I try to search people belonging to a particular department or unit, I couldn't get the search results because department is a custom property.

I have also made full crawl after adding the property. How can I make this work?

Comment: How have you configured the Managed property? Searchable? Retreivable etc? Does it work if you do a "ManagedpropertyName":"IT" search for example?

Comment: ya I have configured everything..but still when I search for a particular department Iam unable to get people in that department

Comment: My question was not "If, but "how" you have configured the property

Comment: If Iam not wrong are u aasking me whether i have enabled the check boxes in managed property?if yes ya i have enabled it.

Comment: Are you searching on the People Vertical? People results are excluded from the default Search Vertical.

Comment: Ya the thing is i could get people search when I search using their respective names,but when I search a department say Engg,HR or IT i want people in those department to be dispalyed

Answer (score 0):

back from SharePoint 2010 I remember that adding a Managed Property is a change in the Search Schema. As such it needed a Full Crawl to become effective. My guess is that this behavior hasn't changed in SharePoint 2013 and that your index doesn't reflect your recent changes yet.

Does this help you?

Cheers
René

Comment: Do you want me to make index reset?

Comment: Can u tell me default webparts available in sharepoint2013 for search